# How to send random class to the new method as an argument

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, random, methods

How to send random class to the new method as an argument?

```
package practice;

import java.util.Random;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator= new Random(seed);
        
        fillMatrixRandom(generator);
        
        
        public static void fillMatrixRandom(int generator) {

    }

}
```

Comment: `generator` is of Type `Random`, not `int.`
it should be  `fillMatrixRandom(Random generator)`.

Comment: Or call `generator.nextInt()`.

Comment: Or call generator.nextInt().

Comment: Or call generator.nextInt(). how to call it

Comment: i couldn't understand it

Answer (score 0):

This method should be like this. Must change data type.

```
public static void fillMatrixRandom(Random generator) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to pass into the method?

-> If you want to pass a single random `int` value, then you should call the `fillMatrixRandom()` method as `fillMatrixRandom(generator.nextInt());`:

```
package practice;

import java.util.Random;

public class test {
    private static int seed = 42;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random(seed);
        
        fillMatrixRandom(generator.nextInt());
    }
    public static void fillMatrixRandom(int generator) {

    }
}
```

-> If you want to pass the random generator into the method (so that it can call `generator.nextInt()` multiple times), then you need to declare the method `fillMatrixRandom()` as `void fillMatrixRandom(Random generator) { /* ... */ }`

```
package practice;

import java.util.Random;

public class test {
    private static int seed = 42;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random(seed);
        
        fillMatrixRandom(generator);
    }
    public static void fillMatrixRandom(Random generator) {

    }
}
```